# Using gnus within emacs to access mail from microsoft exchange(2010)

Tags: emacs, gnus

I am trying to hook up gnus via nnimap to read mail from exchange server. Defined within gnus startup is the configuration info

```
(setq gnus-select-method '(nnimap "example"
              (nnimap-address "mail.server.com")
              (nnimap-server-port 443)
              (nnimap-authenticator login)
              (nnimap-stream ssl)
              (remove-prefix "INBOX.")
              (nnimap-authinfo-file "~/.imap-authinfo")))

(setq imap-ssl-program "openssl s_client -quiet -tls1 -connect %s:%p")
```

Emacs is @`24.0.50.1 (2010-11-16`) and `.imap-authinfo` contains the connection info:

```
machine mail.server.com login my_username password my_password
```

Using openssl and gnutls-cli I can connect to server independently, but emacs hangs when invoking gnus and leaves a message `Opening TLS connection with gnutls-cli --insecure -p 443 mail.server.com'...done`.

Comment: Have you tried running "gnutls-cli -d3 --insecure -p 443 mail.server.com" from the command line? (i.e. with the debug switch set)

Answer (score 5):

I am pretty sure that the best answer was given by @lorexvii.

You must download [Davmail](http://davmail.sourceforge.net/download.html) and follow the instructions for your specific OS.

Then the only thing that Davmail will ask you is the URL for your server (if you don't know which could be the URL this [page](http://davmail.sourceforge.net/gettingstarted.html) gives you some tips).

And finally, you only need to connect Gnus to your local machine, if you don't touch the ports in the settings, for IMAP will be "localhost" and port 1143, username: youruser@yourcompanyemail.com  (yeap, all the email address).

Hope this helps